# charting a stream data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, charts

I've written a small code in node.js to run a web server and send a sequence of 10 numbers to the html file browsed by clients. Below you can find both the node.js code and the html code too.

index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
//
// load the html file
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
console.log(__dirname);
});
//
// 1st attempt of socket
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    // print message to the server
    console.log('Yay, connection was recorded');
    var i = 0;
    var text = "";
    while (i < 10) {
    text = "The number is " + i + "\r\n";
    console.log(text);
    //emit message to all front-end clients
    io.emit('chat message', text);
    i++;
    }
    //handling disconnects
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
   io.emit('chat message', 'some user disconnected');
    });

});    

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/smoothie.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
  });
</script>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm able to see the values 1 to 10 printed within the web page browsed with my client at localhost:3000.

I'm planning now to plot those values using a JavaScript library called smoothie.js. smoothie.js is deployed inside the dir where the index.html is placed but looking at the development console of my broser I've got the following erro:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/smoothie.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I've tried to browse:
 http://localhost:3000/smoothie.js
and I've got the error:
 Cannot GET /smoothie.js

To me it seems the path used for smoothie.js inside the html code is not correct. I've tried different paths but without success. 
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Since you can load your page, your webserver config should be fine. But try checking the smoothie.js file permission. Make sure the webserver can access it. If that doesnt work, show us your webserver log.

Comment: if it's in the same dir as index.html, you need to remove the forward slash --> `<script type="text/javascript" src="smoothie.js"></script>`

Comment: Hi Aus, I've checked the smoothie.js file permission. To me it seems that eevryone can execute the file: -rwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff    41K 21 Lug 20:39 smoothie.js . How to get the webserver log? The server is run inside the index.js code using express.

Comment: Hi WhiteHat, I've removed the forward slash. The result is still the same.